# Maximum number of concurrent requests in a Solr server

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am a newbie to Solr. I would like to know whether there is a limit on the number of concurrent requests being processed by a Solr server. If yes, how does the server handle the requests beyond the limit? Are they queued or dropped by the the server?
Please help me with the question. Thank you.

Comment: Depends what container you run it in and how you configure it, its default is jetty, a high-performance embeddable http server. You're almost certain to run into other performance limitations before number of concurrent requests becomes an issue.

Comment: I second that, pvg. To avoid SolrCloud cross-core deadlocks, the number of threads for the default installation is 10,000. For all practical purposes it will be a slow death by increasing congestion, not a hard fail, when the number of concurrent requests rises.
There is a JIRA for lowering that number, but it is not yet resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7344